# ASP.NET MVC Value cannot be null. on DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an issue with my post-back from a DropDownList. I am trying to create a page which will allow users to create a new skillset, but the skillset links with skill categories, so I am using a DropDownList so that the user can select which category the skillset belongs to, but I am receiving this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

This is my controllers for create:

```
// GET: SkillSets/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var categoryIDs = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Active == 1).Select(x => x.IDCategory).Distinct();
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var t in categoryIDs)
    {
        SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
        s.Text = t.ToString();//db.Categories.Where(c => c.IDCategory == t & c.Active == 1).Select(x => x.Category + ": " + x.C_Role).Single();
        s.Value = t.ToString();
        items.Add(s);
    }
    ViewBag.Campaign = items;
    return View();
}

// POST: SkillSets/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IDSkillset,IDCategory,Product,P_Version,Notes")] Models.SkillSetsModel ss)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SkillSets.Add(ss);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And this is the DropDownList:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDCategory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Campaign", new SelectList(ViewBag.Campaign, "Value", "Text"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDCategory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the model:

```
namespace ITSSkillsDatabase.Models
{
    [Table("SkillSets")]
    public class SkillSetsModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int IDSkillset { get; set; }

        public int IDCategory { get; set; }

        public string Product { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Product Version")]
        public string P_Version { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PersonSkillsModel> PersonSkills { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The DropDownList works for the Get part of the create method, there just seems to be issues with either the view or the Post method, as the DropDownList is being populated.
[image]

Comment: Where are you getting that error? is it in the post or the get of the page?

Comment: What is your model? Why do you have a dropdownlist binding to a property `Campaign` which does not even appear to exist (and is excluded by your `[Bind"` attribute anyway). Why do you create a `SelectList` in the controller and then create another `SelectList` from it in the view?

Comment: @Canvas The Post as the error only occurs when I try to create the skillset, the DropDownList is also fully populated

Comment: @StephenMuecke I editted to include the model, and to be honest, I got that from elsewhere and it worked for the get method, I am fairly new to MVC.

Comment: If I were you don't use the `Bind` to catch what values you want to save. You have a viewmodel so just take your view model as your post parameter and then take a look at what is null in there using a break point.
`public ActionResult Create(SkillSetsModel model)`

Comment: Based on your model it needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IDCategory, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Campaign)`. But you really need to do to the MVC site and work through a few tutorials

Comment: @Canvas done that seems to be the ICollection in the model causing the issue. http://i.imgur.com/Zyk0h4C.png

Comment: @StephenMuecke That fixed the issue, thanks! And yeah I completely agree, I'm going to start running through some at home.

Comment: @TheHornyDonut, Almost every line of your code either does not make sense or is plain bad code and can cause errors. I'll add an answer later to explain some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Campaign", new SelectList(ViewBag.Campaign, "Value", "Text"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IDCategory, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Campaign)
```

fixed the issue, thanks @StephenMuecke!

Comment: btw, this would have worked as `@Html.DropDownList("IDCategory", new SelectList(ViewBag.Campaign, "Value", "Text"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`. When you're binding to a model on post your fields must match the property names

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that you binding the dropdownlist to a property named `Campaign` but you model does not contain a property with that name. Based on the associated label and validation message you want to assign the selected value to property `IDCategory` so in the view it needs to be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IDCategory, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Campaign)
```

Note that the `ViewBag` property is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so using `new SelectList(ViewBag.Campaign, "Value", "Text")` is just pointless extra overhead (you constructing a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the exiting one)

However your code has numerous other errors.

In the GET method, your selecting just the ID property of `Category` and then using `.Distinct()`. If your ID properties are not already unique, it suggests a problem with you database structure. Your also only displaying the ID value in the view which is unlikely to make sense to a user. Assuming `Category` has a property (say) `string Name` to describe the Category, you can simplify your code to

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ViewBag.Campaign = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Active == 1).Select(c => new SelectListItem
  {
    Value = c.IDCategory.ToString(),
    Text = c.Name
  });
  return View(new SkillSetsModel()); // always return a model
}
```

Note the fact that the `IsActive` property is an `int` rather than a `bool` also suggests problems with your database/model design.

In the POST method, you currently redirect to another view if `ModelState` is not valid, meaning the user has no idea that the data they just filled in has not been saved. Then you return the view in the `catch` block without even indicating what the error is, further confusing the user.

Remove the `try/catch` blocks and let the framework handle this until you understand more about handling errors (a default error page will be displayed) and change the code to

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(SkillSetsModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // Return the view so the user can correct errors
    ViewBag.Campaign = ... // as per the GET method
    return View(model);
  }
  db.SkillSets.Add(ss);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Finally I would recommend using view models that represent only the data you want to display/edit in the view (refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)). For your `Create` view, it would not include properties for `IDSkillset` (the object does not exist in the database yet) or `PersonSkills`, but would include a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Campaign` (although `CategoryList` seems a more appropriate name) along with display and validation attributes (a `[Display]` attribute in a data model is not appropriate since it's view specific)